# How to export a VR game for linux using Godot?

Tags: linux, godot, openvr

I'm trying to export a game that use the Godot OpenVr plugin ( https://github.com/GodotVR/godot_openvr ).

I am capable of testing the game through the editor by launching Godot with the command given in Github :
`/home/<user>/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/run.sh`

But when I export it using a Linux/X11, the resulting x86_64 application is not detecting my VR headset, even when I try to launch it via Steam.

Is there any solution to make a self-sufficient executable (or at least directory) that will not need further operation by users?

Comment: Good question, i'm about to get into the whole openvr in godot mess on Linux, i'll post an answer when i find something useful.

Comment: Have you found something useful? I'm working again on my VR game and the Linux Export in on the high priority list, so I'll be looking into that again soon.

Comment: Unfortunately no, war put an end to practically all of my plans, i don't have enough time to even touch Godot at the moment :(